# How to scrape data that comes from drop down list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The website source shows:

```
<div class="content">

    <h2 class="branded">Fixtures</h2>

<div class="mobile-select gameweek-selector-div clearfix">
    <select class="gameweek-selector" >
        <option value="-1">All Season</option>

             <option value="1">Matchweek 1</option>

             <option value="2">Matchweek 2</option>

             <option value="3">Matchweek 3</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

I want to scrape the data when I select one of those option values
the problem is the website url doesn't change it just loads the contents

Comment: how will you parse a thing which is never there??? option is not even selected yet so how can you get selected option with parsing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: i just started with python :).. http://m.premierleague.com/content/mobile/en-gb/fixtures.html im trying to get the fixtures with time,.

Answer (score 1):

Try using your browser's network analyzer.

When I visit the site and select different match weeks, a GET request is sent each time.

For example, here is the request URL for week 1:

`http://m.premierleague.com/pa-services/api/football/mobile/competition/fandr/api/gameweek/1.json`

... and for week 2:

`http://m.premierleague.com/pa-services/api/football/mobile/competition/fandr/api/gameweek/2.json`

Notice the number at the end is all that changed. You can easily loop through your week range making GET requests at each iteration.

Here is a rough sketch of the solution:

```
import json
import urllib

number_of_weeks = 20
base_url = 'http://m.premierleague.com/pa-services/api/football/mobile/competition/fandr/api/gameweek/'

for i in range(1, number_of_weeks+1):
    page = urllib.urlopen(baseurl+str(i)).read()
    json_content = json.loads(page)
    ## now you can do something with the data
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use the mobile page? On the full version you can see every fixture under one page.

http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/matches.html?paramClubId=ALL&paramComp_8=true&view=.dateSeason

Or if you need them to be separated by gameweek

http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/news/news/2015-16/jun/170615-fixture-list-for-2015-2016-season-released.html